# Securing communication between services

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm a noob in GCP and need some recommendations about how to roles and security work in the platform.

I have GCP AppEngine project with several services. Some services need to communicate with other services using HTTP requests.

I want to restrict access to some services and not sure about how can I do it. Do I need to create new roles for each restricted service? How can I authenticate/authorize the caller of the service (OAuth2, apikey...)

I've tried to dive into GCP docs but documentation is a bit generic

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? Could you please add more details to the question as mentioned in [How to ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I haven't tries anything yet. I'd like to manage authentication/authorization on each API Rest in order every endpoint can validate who is calling and check it can access the endpoint. I don't know if. Some service/endpoint will be open, other will be resricted for authenticated users while other service shulod only be available for other services in AppEngine

Answer (score 0):

I do this in a very simple way.  I have a secret key that each service knows about.  When one service calls another service, the requesting service includes the secret key and the responding service checks to make sure it is the right key.

I believe there are also ways to make sure that the requesting service is coming from an app engine server.  I think there are headers that Google only allows for requests from within app engine.  This would give you an extra layer of security.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. How do you supply this secret key? I was thinking about creating some custom roles, one per endpoint. In a "traditional" micro services application I'd probably rely in some sort of Api Gateway. How can I do that with App Engine?

Comment: @Daní, you can provide the secret key in a header like you do with any API that requires authentication credentials.