# How to limit access to google app engine flask endpoints to just application code (or app engine service accounts)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, authorization, service-accounts

Currently building an app on app engine standard environment, with python 3.7 and the flask framework. I need to schedule some tasks which will require the app to run several sensitive endpoints periodically.

**I want to limit access to these endpoints to the application itself, preventing (non-admin) users from accessing these.** In the Python 2 version of app engine, it is possible by specifying `login: admin` in the `app.yaml` file like so:

```
# app.yaml for google app engine standard env python 2

handlers:

  - url: /this_is/my_protected/endpoint
    script: main.app
    login: admin
```

However, **in the Python 3.7 incarnation of the app engine environment, this is no longer possible.**

I understand that it may be necessary to do the authentication in the `main.py` file of my flask app, but I'm not certain where to start.  I already have firebase auth working, and the app is authenticating users fine for several user facing endpoints. However I am not certain how to go about authenticating my own app-engine application (or possibly the service account) to run several of its own endpoints.  I've tried checking the docs, but they're either sparse, or I simply can't find the information I require.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61819119/136598

Comment: I've found the relevant portion of the docs. It seems like it's possible by checking for `X-Appengine-Cron: true` in the http headers for cron requests. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#validating_cron_requests

Comment: If you think this could answer the question and help others, you should post it as a community wiki answer in case this helps other users.

Comment: With the new info in the comment, this question has already been answered [Google App Engine - Securing url of cron python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040050/google-app-engine-securing-url-of-cron-python)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in a comment, here's my simplified (simplistic?) solution to make it such that specific flask end points in google app engine are only accessibly by application code or app engine service accounts.  The answer is based on the documentation regarding [validating cron requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#validating_cron_requests) and [validating task requests](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#reading_app_engine_task_request_headers).

Basically, we write a decorator that will validate whether or not `X-Appengine-Cron: true` is in the headers (implying that the end point is being called by your code, not a remote user). If the header is not found, then we do not run the protected function.

```
# python
# main.py

from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

# Define the decorator to protect your end points
def validate_cron_header(protected_function):
    def cron_header_validator_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#validating_cron_requests
        header = request.headers.get('X-Appengine-Cron')
        # If you are validating a TASK request from a TASK QUEUE instead of a CRON request, then use 'X-Appengine-TaskName' instead of 'X-Appengine-Cron'
        # example:
        # header = request.headers.get('X-Appengine-TaskName')
        # Other possible headers to check can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#reading_app_engine_task_request_headers

        # If the header does not exist, then don't run the protected function
        if not header:
            # here you can raise an error, redirect to a page, etc.
            return redirect("/")

        # Run and return the protected function
        return protected_function(*args, **kwargs)

    # The line below is necessary to allow the use of the wrapper on multiple endpoints
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/42254713
    cron_header_validator_wrapper.__name__ = protected_function.__name__
    return cron_header_validator_wrapper


@app.route("/example/protected/handler")
@validate_cron_header
def a_protected_handler():
    # Run your code here
    your_response_or_error_etc = "text"
    return your_response_or_error_etc


@app.route("/yet/another/example/protected/handler/<myvar>")
@validate_cron_header
def another_protected_handler(some_var=None):
    # Run your code here
    return render_template("my_sample_template", some_var=some_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

It still works in Python 3.x, I use the original approach in my own Flask AppEngine app running Python 3.8

Here is a simplified version of my `app.yaml` with everything you need:

```
runtime: python38
app_engine_apis: true

handlers:
- url: /admin/.*
  secure: always
  script: auto
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto
```

Both scripts are set to auto and point to main.py by default.
In main.py, I define my routes and all routes starting with /admin will force the user to login with a Google Account which has owner/admin rights for the application.

Just make sure you include `app_engine_apis: true` in your `app.yaml` file as it is required for login to work.

Comment: I'm getting 302 status code redirects when I tried this by making requests via the requests library.  Is there a better way to make this request where it knows it's internal, i.e. login:admin is accepted?